# Adding field to requirement only in one project(Azure devops)

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to add another field to requirements items, but only in one of my projects. The only way I found add that specific field to all of my projects requirements .
is it possible to do it?
Note: creating a new item that is not a requirement will not solve the issue, since I need to add the field to items that already exist.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Adding field to requirement only in one project(Azure devops)

The answer is yes.

You could create a inherited processes in the `Organization Settings`-> `Process`:

[Create and manage inherited processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops)

Then create [add a custom field to a work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops) (in Inheritance process)

Now, you just need change the specify project process from xx to the new created Inheritance process.

Similar operation in this document: [Change a project process from Basic to Agile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/change-process-basic-to-agile?view=azure-devops)

In this case, the custom field to requirement workitem type only in othis specify projects.